# Is multiple conda installs more efficient?

Tags: conda

Is there any reason to believe that installing two packages in one command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge package_1 package_2 -y
```

is faster than installing them in two separate commands?

```
conda install -c conda-forge package_1 -y
conda install -c conda-forge package_2 -y
```

? There are some up front steps that seem similar when I run the two commands separately that it seems like it would speed it up, but I don't know the underlying processes and am not sure.

Comment: It is almost a universal fact that doing similar jobs in batch is faster than doing them one by one because shared set-up/tear down tasks only happen once. But I wouldn't really care about how fast installing stuff is because that's something that happens only once, unless maybe when you're making a docker container?

Comment: I'm spinning up a cluster of machines where I need to install requirements, and these clusters get spun up pretty often

Comment: yup, makes sense

Comment: While I'm not entirely sure if it would be faster, installing all the necessary packages at once is considered a best practice (see [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages), for example). You should consider using an `environment.yml` file for this. In your specific cases, are the packages always the exact same, or is there some variation between machines and over time? If you can provide more details on the packages, and how you install them, we might be able to find some improvements.